# Three.js and Opera Shader

Tags: three.js, opera

im running a win 7 x64 with nvidia gt 440.

I'm having this problem with opera 12.15:

```
226: #ifdef USE_SHADOWMAP
227: for( int i = 0; i < MAX_SHADOWS; i ++ ) {
228: vShadowCoord[ i ] = shadowMatrix[ i ] * worldPosition;
229: }
230: #endif
231: }

[13-04-2013 14:49:04] JavaScript - http://www.renatovieira.net/
console.error
Could not initialise shader
VALIDATE_STATUS: true, gl error [1281]
```

Can you help me with this?
I was wondering... if opera can't handle this, can i downgrade three.js disabling this feature?

Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try by disabling shadows from the renderer (`renderer.shadowMapEnabled = false`). You might also need to make sure there aren't any `castShadow` and `receiveShadow` properties set on lights or other objects.

That being said, Opera's WebGL implementation has been known to be fragile in the past, so I wouldn't be surprised if it caught another error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Although i didn't actually tested, because when i upgraded Three.js to r58 (newest at the time) the problem vanished.
Not only in Opera, but also in IE, in which i get a decent render using textures in IE9 & 10.